# Why TCPDF instead of mpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have used both TCPDF and MPDF !!

Just want to know what features of TCPDF make it superior and one have to choose it over MPDF even thought MPDF is much easier to implement than TCPDF ?

Anyone can please explain ?

Thanks

Comment: Please kindly check my answer for your clarification regarding TCPDF & mPDF libraries to generate PDF.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

@Trupti, Please **check below points for your clarification** regarding TCPDF & mPDF.

**1.** TCPDF is the best tool to create booklet covers or non-template based PDFs. It’s excellently supports SVG, PNG and another graphic formats.

**2.** If you would like to generate PDF’s based on some HTML templates — it’s not much good !

**3.** If you want to use HTML templates and create PDFs with look and feel of pure HTML pages — forget about TCPDF and use mPDF instead.

**4.** mPDF is brilliant in converting HTML to PDF with full (or almost full) CSS3 support. However, mPDF doesn’t natively supports SVG format (I guess it uses GD-library for it), doesn't allows to display SVGs with custom fonts, etc.

**5.** mPDF will have better support of custom graphic (including native support of SVG-format), or when Inkscape will allow to convert text-based SVGs to plain SVGs with outlined text.

**Overall Summary :**

**1.** mPDF much more buggy than TCPDF. (TCPDF is extremely stable, it’s author Nicola Asuni very quickly fixes all found bugs, however reluctantly adding new features).

**2.** mPDF doesn’t support text and element strokes. (So, as it said above, if you would like to make some artwork, like booklet covers — use TCPDF instead.)

**3.** TCPDF doesn’t support normal HTML/CSS-rendering.

*You decide what to use depends upon your requirements.*

Comment: It make sense .Thanks @PHP Weblineindia

Comment: Thanks a lot @PHP Weblineindia

Comment: is the above answer still accurate 7 years later?